# Determine if $f=\{(x,y)\mid 2x+3y=7\}$ is invertible. From $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. If it is invert it.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

I am thinking this is no, because I am not even sure if this counts as a function? I am unsure how this can be a function if there exist only a few $(x,y)$s that fulfill the equation.

Or does the $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ mean that the input/output is of the set real numbers, and does not determine that every value in this set must fulfill the function.

Comment: A function $f$ is a set of ordered pairs with the property that if $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x,z)\in f$, then $y=z$.

Comment: I think I understand this but I am unsure on how to apply it to my thinking

Comment: $(x,y)\in f$ is equivalent to $f(x)=y$, so $$f(x)=\frac{7-2x}{3}\text{.}$$

Can you see why that's true?

Comment: @ProbablyWrong Yea I understand, that if you have a coordinate, that the y is a function of x (I think thats the wording) but I am unclear of how the function that finds y helps me

Comment: Well by looking at the expression for $f(x)$ you should be able to see that $f$ is bijective, and then you apply the usual algebraic tricks to find an inverse.

Comment: @ProbablyWrong ah okay I know how to prove bijectivty, but I was just unclear so its safe to assume that any $f(x,y)$ is equivalent to f(x) = y? I guess that it is something I didn't think of.

Comment: @Jude Not all $f(x, y)$ will lead to $f(x)=y$ (e.g. $x=y^2$ is a $f(x, y)$, but $y$ is not a function of $x$), but $Ax+By=C$ for non-zero $A, B$ is always a bijective function because it's a diagonal line.

Comment: @NobleMushtak for the example $x=y^2$ is it not $f(x) = y$ because $\sqrt{x} = y$ which in that case y is not a function of x but the $\sqrt{x} $?

Comment: If $x=y^2$, then $y=\pm \sqrt x$, so for every $x$, there are two values of $y$. In a function, there is only one value of $y$ for every $x$, so this is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand that the **graph** of 2x+ 3y= 7 is a **straight line**?

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is a linear line

Comment: @Jude Other than lines in the form of $x=c$ or $y=c$, lines are always bijective functions in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Oh I didn't know that about lines, I didn't think to graph it but inversing this function is a bit confusing because it is an equation.
Should I look into inversing y=mx+b functions? as this is what it seems like

Comment: The inverse of $y=mx+b$ is always just $y=\frac{x-b}{m}$. Just switch the $x$ and $y$ in the original equation and solve for $y$.